# Split One Column to multi column in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I need solve my problem in TSQL

Current Table

```
TRX      DOC      ITEM      DOCTYPE      QTY
--------------------------------------------
123      ASM1     001       1            100
124      ASM2     002       1             10
234      ADJ1     002       2            -30
456      SAL1     001       3            -20
457      SAL2     002       3            -10
789      PRE1     002       4             10
910      ADJ2     001       2             20
```

How to split column QTY to sum(QTY) AS QTYIN and QTYOUT like this

```
ITEM    QTYIN    QTYOUT   TOTQTY
---------------------------------
 001      120       -10     110
 002       20       -50     -30
```

Thanks for help, I need solution.

Comment: cant understand the logic here. Please explain logic on what you want

Comment: Sum of the positives in one column, sum of the negatives in another is what they are after, grouped by Item.  TotQty is just a SUM

Comment: if that is the case then item 001 has qty 100,-20 and 20. So sum of positive will be 120, sum of negative will be -20 and total qty will be 100. But the Afriadi has written QTYOUT for item 001 as -10 which is wrong i think. AM i correct?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause to combine results by `Item`, then `SUM` with a `CASE` statement to total over specific criteria ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbf90/1)):

```
select
  item,
  sum(case when qty > 0 then qty end) as qtyin,
  sum(case when qty < 0 then qty end) as qtyout,
  sum(qty) as totqty
from
  Table1
group by
  Item
```

Sample Output (I assume the differences are just typos?):

```
| ITEM | QTYIN | QTYOUT | TOTQTY |
----------------------------------
|    1 |   120 |    -20 |    100 |
|    2 |    20 |    -40 |    -20 |
```